# ContextMenu.js label showing label of last entry for all menu items

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, contextmenu

I'm using the ContextMenu for something other then its intended purpose, but the idea seems fine, to label a polyline with distance between points on a google map.

I want the label to show every time I hover the mouse over the polyline showing the distance for that leg. I have no problem determining the distance, however, the label is always showing the distance for the last entry rather then the distance determined for that leg.

I'm creating an array of polylines so that each one can show the distance between points, it all seems to work just fine, except the distance label.

Here is a cut down version of what I'm trying to achieve.

```js
var flightPath = [];
var distanceLables = [];
var map;

function initMap() {
  //Google Map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: -180
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });

  //waypoints for the Polyline
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [{
    lat: 37.772,
    lng: -122.214
  }, {
    lat: 21.291,
    lng: -157.821
  }, {
    lat: -18.142,
    lng: 178.431
  }, {
    lat: -27.467,
    lng: 153.027
  }];

  //drawing each leg of the PolyLine indiviually so that mouseover/mouseout events can be customised to each leg
  for (i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
    var tempCoords = [];
    tempCoords.push(flightPlanCoordinates[i]);
    tempCoords.push(flightPlanCoordinates[i + 1]);
    flightPath.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: tempCoords,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      map: map
    }));

    //Creating the Context Menu which is just one line with the leg number
    var contextMenuOptions = {};
    contextMenuOptions.classNames = {
      menu: 'context_menu displance_display',
      menuSeparator: 'context_menu_separator'
    };
    var menuItems = [];
    menuItems.push({
      className: 'context_menu_item',
      eventName: 'distance_click',
      id: 'distanceItem',
      label: 'Leg #' + i
    }); //Label should represent the leg
    contextMenuOptions.menuItems = menuItems;
    var pos = distanceLables.push(new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions)) - 1;

    //mouseover/mouseout events to show and hide the label
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {
      distanceLables[pos].show(mouseEvent.latLng);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseout', function(mouseEvent) {
      distanceLables[pos].hide();
    });
  }
}
```

```css
    html,

    body {

      height: 100%;

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }

    #map {

      height: 100%;

    }

    .context_menu {

      background-color: #ffff90;

      border: 1px solid gray;

    }

    .context_menu_item {

      padding: 3px 6px;

      background-color: #ffff90;

    }

    .context_menu_item:hover {

      background-color: #4b545f;

      color: #fff;

    }

    .context_menu_separator {

      background-color: gray;

      height: 1px;

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Problem</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
  <script src="http://code.martinpearman.co.uk/googlemapsapi/contextmenu/1.0/src/ContextMenu.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks,

Stu

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip, I've now changed the snippet into a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're defining your labels to display on the mouse events within a loop.  Right now it looks a little like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
    var pos = distanceLables.push(new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions)) - 1;

    google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {
        distanceLables[pos].show(mouseEvent.latLng);
    });
}
```

The line inside the anonymous function doesn't get executed until the mouseover event happens.  So what you're really doing is this:

```
var pos = 0;
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {...});

var pos = 1;
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {...});

var pos = 2;
google.maps.event.addListener(flightPath[i], 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {...});
... etc
```

At the end of your loop, pos = the length of your array - 1, so when you do a mouseover any of the flightpath parts, this line always executes:

```
    distanceLables[pos].show(mouseEvent.latLng);
```

i.e. it's always going to be:

```
    distanceLables[3].show(mouseEvent.latLng);
```

An alternative way to do this might be something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < flightPlanCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
    var pos = distanceLables.push(new ContextMenu(map, contextMenuOptions)) - 1;

    bindLabelEvents(flightPath[i], distanceLables[pos]);
}

var bindLabelEvents = function(polyline, label) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {
        label.show(mouseEvent.latLng);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseout', function(mouseEvent) {
        label.hide();
    });
};
```